# URL is not clickable on standard New record page

Tags: reporting, custom-url

I've created a custom object and using standard page layout to add data to this object (no customized VF page). In this object there is a read-only URL field that assumes some default value, pointing to some reports. At the time of record creation, users should be able to click on this link to view related reports before they can save the data.

When users visit this data entry page, the URL is visible, but its not clickable. In other words, users have to copy and paste the url in a separate browser window.

Any tips (or alternatives) how to achieve it are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Visualforce, you won't be able to do anything about this. The edit page rendition of a page layout doesn't render the same as the detail page.

I would suggest submitting a feature request on the Idea Exchange. If you need this functionality today, you'll need to write a Visualforce page to make clickable links on the edit page.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for your reply. Will have to build a  customized VF page now.